# Java String doesn't get replaced

Tags: java

I have made this small script to test something, but I can't get it working.
I want it to replace the "%20" in the string to " ".
This gets printed out: Ravenous%20Cache.zip

```
package test;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getArchivedName());
    }

    private static String cacheLink = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/Ravenous%20Cache.zip";

    private static String getCacheLink() {
        return cacheLink;
    }

    private static String getArchivedName() {
        String name = cacheLink.replace("%20", " ");
        int lastSlashIndex = name.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (lastSlashIndex >= 0 
            && lastSlashIndex < getCacheLink().length() -1) { 
            return getCacheLink().substring(lastSlashIndex + 1);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Error Downloading Game Files.");
        }
        return "";
    }

}
```

Comment: That's because you are returning a substring of `getCacheLink()` instead of a substring of `name`.

Comment: Works just fine. As RealSkeptic said you are returning the value before it was replaced not after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling getCacheLink() again when you take the substring that gives you back the original string

```
return name.substring(lastSlashIndex + 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Everyone thanks for your posts and I'm sure that you're all right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getArchivedName());
    }

    private static String cacheLink = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/Ravenous%20Cache.zip";

    private static String getCacheLink() {
        return cacheLink;
    }

    private static String getArchivedName() {
        String name = cacheLink.replace("%20", " ");
        int lastSlashIndex = name.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (lastSlashIndex >= 0 
            && lastSlashIndex < getCacheLink().length() -1) { 
            return name.substring(lastSlashIndex + 1);//Changed
        } else {
            System.err.println("Error Downloading Game Files.");
        }
        return "";
    }
```

You were returning `getCacheLink()` not `name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getArchivedName());
    }

    private static String cacheLink = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/Ravenous%20Cache.zip";

    private static String getCacheLink() {
        return cacheLink;
    }

    private static String getArchivedName() {
        cacheLink = cacheLink.replace("%20", " ");
        int lastSlashIndex = cacheLink.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (lastSlashIndex >= 0 && lastSlashIndex < getCacheLink().length() - 1) {
            return getCacheLink().substring(lastSlashIndex + 1);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Error Downloading Game Files.");
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ravenous Cache.zip is what you get after running this.